# Are Subnet ID's and Route Table ID's unique across VPC's?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Can 2 different Subnets or Route Tables have the same ID if they belong to different VPC's? Or they are unique across the account?

Answer (score 0):

Subnet ID and Route Table ID are generated by AWS itself. It's internal to AWS whether the ID's are unique across a VPC or an Account or the Region or the entire AWS. AWS may be using one namespace today and change it in future. So, we should not rely on assuming any namespace for their ID's.
A Subnet or a Route Table will have to be referred in the context of a given VPC.